# Add cypress dashboard record key in cypress config file

Tags: cypress

I have added my cypress record key in the cypress config file. But displaying this issue. Can someone help me to resolve this issue?
[image]

Tried like this too.

```js
 e2e: {
async setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  // implement node event listeners here
  const bundler = createBundler({
    plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin(config)],
  });

  on("file:preprocessor", bundler);
  await addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  return config;
},

specPattern:"cypress/e2e/features/*feature",
baseUrl:"https://d2l5front.net/",
projectId: "7t2",
viewportWidth: 1600,
viewportHeight: 1100,

env: {
  CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: "62ad7c5d-2c01209cf1c7",
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The `CYPRESS_` prefix is only for "external" environment variables, those created in the OS before Cypress runs.

See [Option #3: CYPRESS_*](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#Option-3-CYPRESS_)

> Cypress automatically normalizes both the key and the value.
> **The leading CYPRESS_ or cypress_ is removed** and the remaining name is camelCased, while values are converted to Number or Boolean wherever possible.

I would suggest you try without the `CYPRESS_` prefix since you are providing the key "internally" as it were.

```js
env: {
  RECORD_KEY: "62ad7c5d-2c01209cf1c7",
}
```

Comment: tried this still the same

Answer (score 1):

I think that is by design. The record key should not be saved in the config (or any) file, as it's linked to billable usage.

From [Dashboard - Record key](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/dashboard/projects#Record-key)

> **Exposing a record key**
>
> Anyone that has access to both the **projectId** and the **record key** of a project can record runs to that organization's project in the Dashboard.

The `projectId` can be saved as

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  projectId: 'a7bq2k'
})
```

but there is no mention of setting `recordKey` in the config.

Instead, you must set it in the external environment as `CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY` or on the command line

```js
cypress run --record --key abc-key-123
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `env` property should be under the `e2e` object, not at the same level.

```js
...
e2e: {
  ...
  env: {
    CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY: 'foo',
  },
  ...
}
...
```

Comment: Hey, actually can you remove your exact record key and projectId from both this comment and your original? Anyone with those can use your Cypress dashboard account -- working on figuring out what the exact issue is though.

Comment: Ah, I think I might have it -- instead of using `CYPRESS_RECORD_KEY`, can you try `record_key`?

Comment: Also - since your record key has been exposed, you'll probably want to trash that one and create a new one that hasn't been exposed.

Comment: Hi, This is not my real record key.It s a fake key

Comment: Even in the screenshot?

Comment: yes its also fake